# Is it beneficial to reduce the number of calls to useState in this way？

Tags: reactjs

Should I use `useRef` to save `count, page, perPage` and `update` the unified control view rendering.
How to optimize this code in a better way?

```
function LogTable(props) {
    const {queryText, menuKey, parentKey} = props;
    const count = React.useRef(1);
    const page = React.useRef(0);
    const perPage = React.useRef(20);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'username',
                accessor: 'username',
                width: '10%',
                Cell: ({value}) => <span>{(value && value.split('@')[0]) || ""}</span>
            },
            {
                Header: 'menu',
                accessor: 'menu',
                width: '10%',
            },
            {
                Header: 'time',
                accessor: 'time',
                width: '15%',
            },
            {
                Header: 'operation',
                accessor: 'operation',
            },
        ],
        []
    );

    const updatePage = (newPage) => {
        page.current = newPage;
        setUpdate(u => u + 1);
    };

    const updatePerPage = (newPerPage) => {
        page.current = 0;
        perPage.current = newPerPage;
        setUpdate(u => u + 1);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (update !== 0) {
            page.current = 0;
            setUpdate(u => u + 1);
        }
    }, [menuKey, parentKey, queryText]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            setLoading(true);
            fetchActions({
                url: 'url',
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    keyword: queryText,
                    menu_key: menuKey,
                    page: page.current + 1,
                    parent_key: parentKey,
                    size: perPage.current,
                }),
                success: body => {
                    const data = body.data;
                    count.current = data.logs_count;
                    setData(data.logs);
                },
                complete: () => {
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [update]);


    return (
        <Table data={data} columns={columns} count={count.current} loading={loading} updatePage={updatePage}
               updatePerPage={updatePerPage} perPage={perPage.current}/>
    )
}

export default LogTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

With React, the view should flow from the state of the component. Using refs instead of state should only be done when there aren't any other good options. Using a hack like `setUpdate(u => u + 1);` to force an update right after you've set a ref doesn't help anything - it'd make a whole lot more sense to just use state instead. Performance of the app will be the same, and the code will make a lot more sense.

```
const { useState } = React;
function LogTable(props) {
    const {queryText, menuKey, parentKey} = props;
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(20);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        // ...
    );

    const updatePerPage = (newPerPage) => {
        setPerPage(newPerPage);
        setPage(0);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (update !== 0) {
            setPage(0);
        }
    }, [menuKey, parentKey, queryText]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            setLoading(true);
            fetchActions({
                url: 'url',
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    keyword: queryText,
                    menu_key: menuKey,
                    page: page + 1,
                    parent_key: parentKey,
                    size: perPage,
                }),
                success: ({ data }) => {
                    setCount(data.logs_count);
                    setData(data.logs);
                },
                complete: () => {
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [update]);


    return (
        <Table data={data} columns={columns} count={count.current} loading={loading} updatePage={setPage}
               updatePerPage={updatePerPage} perPage={perPage.current}/>
    )
}

export default LogTable;
```

It's perfectly fine to call two state setters at once, eg

```
setPerPage(newPerPage);
setPage(0);
```

This will result in only a single re-render, not two. (unless there's an effect hook or something observing the changed state variables, which isn't the case here...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which resolved my long-term doubts！